# Is it possible to create an empty or dummy index in postgres?

Tags: postgresql, index

I am working on cleaning up a database so that an application upgrade script can run. The state is that the upgrade script expects an index to exist only so that it can drop that index. The index was dropped in production by hand some time ago. Artificially altering the upgrade script or telling the upgrade process it has already run that step isn't an option for non-technical reasons beyond my control.

Instead of taking the time to recreate the index is it possible to create a "dummy" or empty index with the same name so that the upgrade script can run?

This is for postgresql 9.0 or later.

Comment: To create a "dummy" index you could use a partial index that excludes all rows: `create index empty_ind on foo(id) where false`;

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> upgrade script expects an index to exist only so that it can drop that index [...] Instead of taking the time to recreate the index is it possible to create a "dummy" or empty index with the same name so that the upgrade script can run?

Just delete that line from the update script. Or even better, use the `IF EXISTS` clause so it throws a notice not an error.

```
Command:     DROP INDEX
Description: remove an index
Syntax:
DROP INDEX [ CONCURRENTLY ] [ IF EXISTS ] name [, ...] [ CASCADE | RESTRICT ]
```

But yes, the `DROP INDEX` doesn't even know if the index is on a specified table if you're dropping by index name and not by `table(column)` location.

Here is an example,

```
CREATE TABLE foo ( x int );
CREATE INDEX ON foo(x);
CREATE TABLE bar ( LIKE foo );

\d foo;
      Table "public.foo"
 Column |  Type   | Modifiers 
--------+---------+-----------
 x      | integer | 
Indexes:
    "foo_x_idx" btree (x)

--
-- HERE WE DROP FOR THE FIRST TIME
--
DROP INDEX foo_x_idx ;
DROP INDEX

--
-- RECREATE
--
CREATE INDEX foo_x_idx ON bar(x);

--
-- DROP AGAIN
--
DROP INDEX foo_x_idx;
DROP INDEX
```

Comment: "Just delete that line from the update script." - Not an option in this case. I don't control the software and the customer wants to avoid risk by telling the application that its already run the script. I'll edit my question to clarify

Comment: @Freiheit I don't see how running the script through `sed` to delete a line is less safe than modifying the state the script assumes, but to each their the own, I updated with an example.